# MQTT on a RPi Pico - script fails due to timeout (I think)

Tags: mqtt, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Apologies for the basic request here.  I have a Pico Enviro+ and am using the script [here](https://github.com/pimoroni/pimoroni-pico/blob/main/micropython/examples/pico_enviro/enviro_all_mqtt.py) to send data to my MQTT server.

The script fails after approx 12-14hrs.  It used to fail after 5-6hrs, but I changed the MQTT keepalive from 30 to 60 seconds.

My question is:  does anyone have a better method than the one in the script for keeping alive (a) WiFi and (b) MQTT client connection.  Otherwise I won't be able to put the bloody thing outside.

Apologies again for the very basic nature of my question.  I know this isn't my own training space, I just need pointers...

TIA

Comment: The keepalive really shouldn't matter as the client connects/disconnects for every message. This implies it's a WiFi connection problem not a MQTT problem

Comment: will investigate the wifi keep alives